# "Many children don't play ball" or "Many children doesn't play ball"

Tags: grammar, verbs, tenses, present-tense, do

I'm still learning English and the topic which I learn is about simple present tense. I'm learning from channel learnenglishlab. But there is one video I don't understand why it using do rather than does.

The sentence is: "Many children don't play football". The correct word is don't or doesn't? The video tells the answer is don't Children are the plural form of child right? so why the verb is not doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Children* is plural; *does* and *doesn't* are third person singular (contrast *she does* with *they do*)

Comment: So because does and doesn't is third-person singular it's cannot be used by "many children"? is it because the children itself is a plural word? And what POV is "many children" is?

Comment: The child does not play football. The children **do** not play football.

Comment: The OP may find "children" difficult: it is plural without *s* on the end.

Answer (score 1):

The subject of the sentence is debatable. Is it "many" or is it "children"?

The fact is that it doesn't make any difference to the verb because "many" is plural. In fact you can use it on its own, e.g.

*There are 100 children in this school. Many don't play football.*

---

**Here's the rule**

**"many" takes a plural verb**

*Many people waste time*

**"much" takes a singular verb**

*Much time is wasted by people*